# For-Loop Problems

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have the following function which will take in a list of 2D lists of size NxN, for example:

```py
print(matrix)

[

[ [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], 
  [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], 
  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], 
  [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0] ], 
[ [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], 
  [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 1.0], 
  [8.0, 0.0, 2.0, 4.0], 
  [1.0, 9.0, 5.0, 8.0] ]

]
```

Each "matrix" is actually a 2D list both with dimension = 4; making 'matrix' a 3D list with two 2D list entries. The function below will take in the dimension of the 2D list, some number of time periods (say 3), age_classes (again suppose 3), and 'values' which would be the 3D list from above.

```py
def initial_values_ext(dimension,periods,age_classes,values):

    dicts = {}
    dict_keys = range(dimension)
    time_keys = range(periods)
    age_keys = range(age_classes)

    for i in dict_keys:
        for j in dict_keys:
            for t in time_keys:
                for k in age_keys:
                    if t == 0:
                        dicts[i+1,j+1,t+1,k+1] = values[k][i][j]
                    else:
                        dicts[i+1,j+1,t+1,k+1] = 1
    return dicts
```

The function 'initial_values_ext' will then pass those 2D lists and generates a dictionary. Each 2D list corresponded with an age class - so the first 2D list would be age_classes = 1 and the second 2D list would be age_classes = 2, and if there was an additional 2D list then it would correspond to age_classes = 3, and so on. So if we were to call the function, then a couple of the outputs might look like the following:

```py
initial_values_ext(dimension=4, periods=3, age_classes=2,values=matrix)

(1,1,1,1):1.0
(1,1,1,2):2.0
(1,1,2,2):1.0

(3,4,1,1):7.0
(3,4,1,2):5.0
(3,4,2,1):1.0
```

So the final output would be a full dictionary of values that starts at (1,1,1,age_class=1):1.0 and ends at (4,4,2,age_class=2):8.0. Importantly, the resulting dictionary will pull from the first 2D list of 'matrix' when age_class=1 and will pull from the second 2D of 'matrix' when age_class=2

Edit: Below I have included the code that I have made for when the input matrix is only a list of lists and when there is no fourth entry of the dictionary.

```py
matrix = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]]

def initial_values(dimension,periods,values):
    dicts = {}
    dict_keys = range(dimension)
    time_keys = range(periods)
    for i in dict_keys:
        for j in dict_keys:
            for t in time_keys:
                if t == 0:
                    dicts[i+1,j+1,t+1] = values[i][j]
                else:
                    dicts[i+1,j+1,t+1] = 1
    return dicts
```

Output:

```py
initial_values(4,2,matrix)

{(1, 1, 1): 1.0,
 (1, 1, 2): 1,
 (1, 2, 1): 2.0,
 (1, 2, 2): 1,
 (1, 3, 1): 3.0,
 (1, 3, 2): 1,
 (1, 4, 1): 4.0,
 (1, 4, 2): 1,
 (2, 1, 1): 5.0,
 (2, 1, 2): 1,
 (2, 2, 1): 6.0,
 (2, 2, 2): 1,
 (2, 3, 1): 7.0,
 (2, 3, 2): 1,
 (2, 4, 1): 8.0,
 (2, 4, 2): 1,
 (3, 1, 1): 1.0,
 (3, 1, 2): 1,
 (3, 2, 1): 2.0,
 (3, 2, 2): 1,
 (3, 3, 1): 3.0,
 (3, 3, 2): 1,
 (3, 4, 1): 4.0,
 (3, 4, 2): 1,
 (4, 1, 1): 5.0,
 (4, 1, 2): 1,
 (4, 2, 1): 6.0,
 (4, 2, 2): 1,
 (4, 3, 1): 7.0,
 (4, 3, 2): 1,
 (4, 4, 1): 8.0,
 (4, 4, 2): 1}
```

Comment: Most likely, your `matrix` is 3D list and in your function you are treating it like a 2D list.

Comment: What does the input matrix look like (1 list with 8 or 9 rows, 9 separate lists), and based on that input matrix what is the actual desired/expected output?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I edited the body so you can see the full input matrix and updated what the desired output would be. If that is not more clear, let me know and i'll try to see what else I can come up with.

Comment: Just As I suspected Your matrix is a 3D list. You either want to loop over it in the function or pass an item from it to the function.

Comment: Might be just me, but it is confusing trying to get from the input to the output. Will every matrix entry have 1 and only 1 dict entry? Maybe if you could show the output you expect from the first and last rows or if you are looking at columns or something else?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I edited the code at the end which includes the function call that I made for the case of the input matrix only being a list of lists, and with no "age_class" parameter. My goal is to essentially add this parameter into the dictionary to up the complexity. But as you can see in the example at the end, the dictionary only pulls from the input matrix when (i,j,t=1) but for (i,j,t=2) the value of the dictionary defaults to 1. With my extension, I only want the t = 1 entries to be pulled, and then depending on the age_class, it'll pull from the 1st or 2nd 2D array.

Comment: Dude you missed `k` index in values. It should be `values[k][i][j]`

Comment: @Ashwani I tried this, but for some reason I keep getting an IndexError: List index out of Range

Comment: @D.Gray I literally copy pasted you code with just one change mentioned in my previous comment. And it worked just fine (No IndexError).

Comment: @Ashwani I think that is the answer! I restarted both of the kernels on my Jupyter notebooks and now it appears to be functioning properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications to make your approach more pythonic.

```
def initial_values_ext(dimension, periods, age_classes, values):
    x = list(map(range,[dimension, periods, age_classes]))
    dicts = {(i+1,j+1,t+1,k+1) : values[k][i][j] if t==0 else 1 \
             for i in x[0] for j in x[0] for t in x[1] for k in x[2]}
    return dicts
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It's helpful to see how things can be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

The function call was missing an additional looping index when 'values' are called:

```py
def initial_values_ext(dimension,periods,age_classes,values):

    dicts = {}
    dict_keys = range(dimension)
    time_keys = range(periods)
    age_keys = range(age_classes)

    for i in dict_keys:
        for j in dict_keys:
            for t in time_keys:
                for k in age_keys:
                    if t == 0:
                        dicts[i+1,j+1,t+1,k+1] = values[k][i][j] 
                    else:
                        dicts[i+1,j+1,t+1,k+1] = 1
    return dicts
```